# How do I configure my PhpMyAdmin to connect to a MariaDB from another network?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, xampp

I have a computer inside a LAN network at my workplace which hosts the MariaDB database from Xampp and which is accessed through PhpMyAdmin. It is accessible throughout the LAN at the workplace, however we need it to be accessible through the PhpMyAdmin UI from an outside network (different building in another city).

How exactly would I go with configuring the files for the outside client to connect to the database in our LAN? From what I've studied all I could see was how to configure for it to work within the same LAN.

Answer (score -1):

Because I don't know your specific ip and parameter values, I can only give you the method. The specific method is as follows:

1. First of all, you should ensure that the networks at both ends are in normal communication; Whether it is in the form of public network or vpn;
2. hosts visited by users need to be configured correctly, when you create users or use alter;

3.bind_address needs to be configured correctly